# Show loading dialog while modal transition using storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I'm trying to use storyboard for the first time and I have a problem.

I need to show a loading dialog while a modal view controller is loading.

I'll explain it better: I have a button on my navigationbar, and when a user clicks on it a modal view controller appears but it takes some seconds so I need to say to user, "The app is not locked".

**Update**

this is the final code that works properly:

```
-(void)showLoading {

    UIActivityIndicatorView *loading = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    loading.frame = CGRectMake(275, 0, 40, 40);
    [loading startAnimating];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^ {

        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:loading]];

    } completion: ^(BOOL completed) {

        UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
        [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];

    }];

}
```

and in `viewDidLoad`

```
[myBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
[myBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(visualizzaCaricamento)];
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to use the built in `UIActivityIndicator`. It comes in large and small varieties. You can place it in a view over everything, or you could add it to your `UINavigationBar`.

Here is a bit of code that would replace the button with a loading spinner.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[indicator startAnimating];

[self.navigationBar setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:indicator]];
```

**Update**

```
// In your viewDidLoad or somewhere like that.
[self.navigationBar setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Do" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(doSomething:)]];

- (void)doSomething:(id)sender {
    // Show spinner
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
    [self.navigationBar setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:indicator]];
    [indicator startAnimating];

    // ... Load View
}
```

Comment: I put it in viewWillDisappear method, there is a better way to implement it? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Either there or you could put it in the actual button tap method.

Comment: I'm trying this 

[myBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(showLoading)];

But doesn't work

Comment: I'll update my answer with more code. That isn't how it should be done.

Comment: I've already done what you've write. The problem now is how to load view beacause I'm using storyboard; now I'm trying a things like [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"nextView" sender: self]; I'm on right path?

Comment: You are on the right path. You may need to instantiate the view yourself from storyboard. then present it rather than using an explicit segue.

Comment: I've posted a solution for all those who have the same problem.